# Why changing font in Inkscape does not work?

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to change the font of "x" in the figure below. I selected it with "Select" (the arrow icon) and then clicked on "Create and Edit Text" (the A icon) and I think the thin dashed line around x means that it is selected. Then I expected to be able to adjust its properties in the text toolbar on top, but to no avail. I changed the font to 10 size and nothing happened. I changed it "Perpetua" again nothing. Why? As far as I can deduce from the click menu the image is not grouped nor frozen.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but we know nothing of the structure of your drawing. The x can be a symbol, a clone or a path or something which is got from elsewhere and its "read only" in Inkscape. It can be under a multilevel group or clipping path. It can be a linked object. Show what the Objects panel says of your x . Try to select it also with the node tool to see is it a path.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I checked Objects panel and that x is a path. Your comment answers your question, so if you make it into an answer I will approve it.

Comment: There's the same already as an answer and as a well written one. Accept it to mark "no problem any more, case closed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the x might not editable text, for example text which has been converted to outlines will no longer be editable as text.

You can tell by clicking and dragging on the text with the text tool. Should look like this if it's editable text, it will be highlighted.

[image]

You can also tell by simply selecting the text box using the Select Tool (S), and check the status bar at the bottom of the edit window. If it's a text object it will say so.

[image]

If you can't do that, but can select the paths using the Edit Path by Nodes Tool (N) and it looks like this below, then you have outlines, and not editable text.

[image]

All may not be lost however, if you know what the font is and already have it installed, you can just type it again, and delete the old one.  Simply choose the Text tool, click and type the letters you want. Highlight the text, and change the font to the one you want, set the size, and click and drag to reposition it.